# How to know that a onclick event is called from mouseclick or pressing the enter key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application and I have an anchor tag with a `onclick` event.

If I will press the tab and when the focus comes on this anchor then via pressing the enter key `clickMe` also called.

How do I can check inside the  `clickMe` function that it is called via mouse click or pressing the enter key.

My code is below. I have tried with `event.type` and `event.keyCode` but it not worked for me. Sandbox link is https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-fpmvy

import React, { Component } from "react";

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {}
  clickMe = (e) => {
    console.log("I am called")
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <a href="#" onClick={(e)=>this.clickMe(e)}>Country</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You're using an "onClick", so it will only get fired for a click, not a keypress.... right? Also, you can check the `event.type`

Comment: Yes @TJBlackman, I am using onClick and its called on pressing the enter also, inside the function I would like to know that it is called from mouse click or called from via pressing the enter key.

Comment: Why would you even want that in the first place? Users who mainly use the keyboard to navigate web pages will _expect_ both things to lead to the same result. Messing with such expectations and deviating from established schemes like that, does not sound like a good idea to begin with.

Comment: Add onkeypress={e =>e.preventDefault()} to your html EDIT: However I agree with @CBroe, don't do it unless you really don't want it

Comment: A piece of advice: If you will not pass any other parameters to `clickMe` function, don't declare a new anonymous function for onClick handler. Instead use the following syntax:  `<a href="#" onClick={this.clickMe}>Country</a>` JavaScript will automatically pass the event parameter to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only hacky way I found to distinguish if the click is from mouse or the keyboard is to use the [`event.screenX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/screenX) and [`event.screenY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/screenY) properties. If the event isn't triggered from the screen, both values will be zeros.

```
clickMe = e => {
    if (e.screenX === 0 && e.screenY === 0) {
      // event not triggered from the screen.
      console.log("not from screen");
    } else {
      // clicked by the mouse.
    }
  };
```

Here is a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-4usdk?file=/src/App.js:86-329)

Comment: Yes this solution is working for me, Thanks a lot to you.

Comment: Yes, this is the only hacky way i found.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava first of all Thanks for editing the question. As you said it is a hack,   Is there any loop hole on this? I tested this in my application working fine for me.

Comment: this answer is not working for windows + latest chrome browser